# Difference and Difference in regression

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, data-visualization, panel-data

What is the idea behind difference in difference? and what do we use the difference in difference for?

Is difference in difference related to Ordinary Least Squares? (OLS)

Comment: Hi Aqsa. You can use OLS to run a difference-in-differences (DD) model. This previous [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564/what-is-difference-in-differences) may address most of your concerns. Do you have any questions more specifically about how to apply this approach?

Comment: Hi zbicyclist,how do we apply this approach?

Comment: The post I referenced will undoubtedly answer your question. I would give it a read and follow-up here if you have something specific about a DD application. As your question stands now, my answer would mirror Andy’s response. I can clarify anything further here :)