# DiD with differing durations of pre-start and post-start periods by individual

Tags: generalized-did

Referencing this [Q/A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564/what-is-difference-in-differences), Andy offers two models that return the DiD lift estimate.

Eq1:
=([|=,=2]−[|=,=1])−([|=,=2]−[|=,=1])

Eq2: =1+2(treat)+3(time)+(treat⋅time)+

From appearances, the  in eq1 is the same as  in eq2, which is the lift attributable to treatment exposure under parallel trends assumption.

[|=,=2] =  1+2+3++

[|=,=1] =  1+2+

[|=,=2] =  1+3+

[|=,=1] =  1+

So, the following should be true:  = [ (1+2+3++) - (1+2+)] - [ (1+3+) - (1+) ]. Doing some algebra, both sides are reduced to  = . Great!

**Question**

However, suppose that the duration of pre-start period and post-start period varied by individual in the natural experiment.

My questions are:

1. Is this allowed?
2. What is the appropriate modeling choice?